# what is Comparable in java?

Tags: java, comparable

I know Comparable is an interface, but I saw some codes like `ArrayList<Comparable>`, `public Comparable f()`,`public void f(Comparable a)`.
It seems like Comparable is a class. How do those codes above implement?

```
import java.util.*;
public class MinHeap
{
    public  MinHeap()
    {
        elements = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
        elements.add(null); 
    }
    ....
}

public class BinarySearchTree
{
    ...
    public void add(Comparable obj)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.data = obj;
        newNode.left = null;
        newNode.right = null;
        if (root == null) root = newNode;
        else root.addNode(newNode);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: `It seems like Comparable is a data type` Huh?

Comment: I would like to see these code. It is extremely rare to use `Comparable` in such ways.

Comment: If you saw such things in code, it was probably not good code, or very old, as `Comparable<T>` is a *generic* type, so all of those declarations should have had its base type mentioned.

Comment: @RealSkeptic absolutely. Raw types are terrible.

Comment: I added type parameters above since code using generics without supplying type parameters should be fixed.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea: I've reverted your change. You can't actually *compare* two elements of an `ArrayList<Comparable<?>>`. The right fix is usually to use a bounded type parameter `T extends Comparable<T>` and have an `ArrayList<T>`, but making that fix in the question would be too dramatic a change. It belongs in an answer.

Comment: @user2357112 good call. It get intractable and it seriously changes the question. That was bad judgment on my part ;)

Comment: @AlainO'Dea The general rule of thumb for SO edits is not to change anything in a question's code other than its formatting.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I break that rule too often. I'll rein that in now. Thank you for the pointer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What those uses of Comparable mean is that they accept an object of any class that implements the Comparable interface.

But Comparable is still an interface.  You can't specifically create an object of type Comparable, but you can assign an instance of a class that implements it to a variable of that type.  For example, if there is a class Foo that implements Comparable, e.g.

```
public class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {
    public int compareTo(Foo o) {...}
}
```

then I can treat objects of class Foo as Comparables.  If I have an array list like:

```
List<Comparable> list = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
```

I can put Foo objects in it, because they implement Comparable, e.g.

```
list.add(new Foo());
```

Comment: polymorphism at it's finest